# How to use IPC (Inter-Process Communication) to open an another app using its package id and send/receive data

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, native, ipc, ionic5

**1) Requirement**

- To generate a symmetric key to encrypt a password and send to a another app by storing it in a content provider
- Send via IPC (Inter-Process Communication)

**2) My App Config**

- Using Ionic cordova App
- Ionic Version 5
- I have tried with in-app-browser but getting error while using
  `window.cordova.plugins.Browser.open({ url });` 
  Error -  Property 'Browser' does not exist on type 'CordovaPlugins'